# Increase disk allocation for Elastic Search on linux

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

We are trying to index large datasets to elastic search and indexing is stopped due to watermark reached and nodes are set to read-only.

We ran the command

```
GET /_cat/allocation?v
```

and from the output, we came to know that the disk space allocated for elastic is 10Gb and 95% is occupied.
We have some more free space on our machine that can be allocated to elastic.

We are trying to figure out how to increase the space allocation to elastic search.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: ES will take whatever space is available in `path.data`.

Comment: Just having 10 GB storage is really scary because the Operating System and its basic softwares itself need around 10GB

Comment: We do have space on the disk available... we tried running free -g command and we see around 15gb available... We are unable to figure out how to tell elastic to use that
sounds trivial but we are trying to understand where elastic search saves data and how to how it calculates the available space and is trying to tell Elastic Search to use the space avaialble instead of restricting itself to 10GB

Answer (score 0):

Increase disc capacity to 100GB(based on data need) from 10GB(In AWS just upsized EBS volume) and follow below steps

> connect to your instance

[ec2-user ~]$ **df -hT**

Filesystem      Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  xfs   8.0G  1.6G  6.5G  20% /
/dev/nvme1n1    xfs   8.0G   33M  8.0G   1% /data

[ec2-user ~]$ **lsblk**

NAME          MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme1n1       259:0    0  30G  0 disk /data
nvme0n1       259:1    0  16G  0 disk
└─nvme0n1p1   259:2    0   8G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p128 259:3    0   1M  0 part

[ec2-user ~]$ **sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1**

[ec2-user ~]$ **sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1**

Reference : We followed the recomendation form here. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Comment: Thank You will try these steps and get back

Comment: growpart and resize2fs  commands are file system based. Check in thw aws url for different filesyetm commands.